# If I have a polynomial $x^2(1-m^2) - x2m^2 - (m^2 + 1)$ with a solution at $x = -1$, how do I get the other root

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, quadratic-forms

If I have a polynomial $x^2(1-m^2) - x2m^2 - (m^2 + 1)$ with a solution at $x = -1$, then I know I can just take $x^2(1-m^2) - x2m^2 - (m^2 + 1)$ and divide it by $x+1$ to get the other root.

In a similar manner, if I have $x^2(m^2 + 1) + x(2m-2m^2) + (m^2 - 1)$ with a solution at $x = 1$, then I know I can just take $x^2(m^2 + 1) + x(2m-2m^2) + (m^2 - 1)$ and divide it by $x-1$ to get the other root.

Problem is when I tried long division here for both, I get such a ridiculous mess that I don't know how to move on. In a similar fashion, wolframalpha doesn't help either. Just in case I my polynomials are wrong, here is where I derived them from:

For the first one I had the two equations: $y = m(x-1) + 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ so I put the first one into the second one and simplified.

For the second one I had the two equations: $y = m(x+1)$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 1$. Similarly I put the first one into the second one and simplified.

I would be very grateful if I could get the second root of each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the quadratic equation $(1-m^2)x^2-2m^2 x-(m^2+1)=0$, the product of the roots is $\frac{-(m^2+1)}{1-m^2}$. Since $-1$ is one of the roots, the other must be $\frac{1+m^2}{1-m^2}$.

The same method can be used for any quadratic equation with one known root.

**Remark:**  Please check the calculation of the coefficients of the quadratics. For example, when we substitute $y=m(x-1)+1$ in $x^2+y^2=2$, we do not get your first quadratic, nor your second, though that one is much closer.

The equations $y=m(x-1)+1$ and $x^2+y^2=2$ were written down in order to give a rational parametrization of the quadratic. If you want to use $y=m(x-1)+1$, then one of the roots of the resulting quadratic will be $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: Im not sure I follow what you did. How did you get the other root?

Comment: For $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the product $r_1r_2$ of the roots is $\frac{c}{a}$. So if we know $r_1\ne 0$, then $r_2=\frac{c}{r_1a}$. In our case $r_1=-1$, so $r_2=-\frac{c}{a}$.

Comment: Some of your calculations are not right. Once you have the right equations, and the right quadratic, the calculation of the second root is as I described in the answer. But let us go back to basics to get the whole thing right. We are looking at the circle $x^2+y^2=2$. We will draw lines with slope $m$ throgh a certain fixed point. Which point? There are several good choices, some combination of $\pm 1$ with $\pm 1$. Which one are you using? If you tell me that, I can write down the right equation for the line, find the quadratic, and find the other root as described in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I appreciate it. I am using the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: OK. Then when we substitute $y=mx-(m-1)$ in $x^2+y^2=2$, we get $(1+m^2)x^2 -2m(m-1)x+(m-1)^2-2=0$. Quite different from the one you used. Also, the obvious root is $x=1$, and the product of the roots is $\frac{(m-1)^2-2}{1+m^2}$, so the other root is $\frac{(m-1)^2-2}{1+m^2}$. Please check my calculation, I am both typo and mistake-prone.

Comment: But if we are using the point $(1,1)$, then wouldn't the point slope formula give us $y-1 = m(x-1) \Rightarrow y = m(x-1)+1$. Thats how I did it for both problems.

Comment: Sure, you wrote $y=m(x-1)+1$, I wrote $y=mx-(m-1)$. Same thing, my version is in preparation for squaring.

Comment: I am not getting what you got. I get $(m(x-1)+1)^2$ to be what I got. What would be the problem? Whats interesting is that when I rewrote you $y$ and did it I got what you got but they are technically the same thing.

Comment: Ahh yes I see what I did. It was just another rearranging problem. I got it though. Thanks for you help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. Algebra is treacherous. I rewrote as $y=mx-(m-1)$ because I was going to square, and was buying insurance against error. In real life I would not even have computed the quadratic. All we need is the coefficient of $x^2$ and the constant term.

Answer (score 1):

To do polynomial division in such cases, you may want to consider the following approach: I shall illustrate with your title problem.

```
-1  | (1-m^2)    -2m^2  -(m^2+1)
    |    0       -1+m^2    1+m^2               
    -------------------------------
       1-m^2     -1-m^2   |  0
```

This gives you the factorisation $(x+1)\left((1-m^2)x-(1+m^2)\right)$ from which the second root is clear.

Comment: More on this if you're interested is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#Regular_synthetic_division